# Should i add an ID for many-to-many relation table in my asp.net MVC

Tags: sql-server-2008, database

i am working on a hotel reservation system using asp.net MVC 3 and i have the following tables:-

1. Customer table that have:-

   Customer_ID (PK)

   FirstName

   DateOfBirth

   etc...
2. Room table

   Room_number (PK)

   Type

   etc...

for the reservation i have two approaches either by having

1. Reservation

   Room_number (FK)

   Customer_Id (FK)

   Date

   Price

Having `PK (Room_number & Customer_Id & Date)` since that same room cannot be reserved by the same customer at the same day.

OR i can build the reservation table as following; by adding a reservation ID to my Reservation table instead of having the PK consists of three columns which will ease the code for retrieving , updating the reservation object, as follow:-

1. Reservation

   Reservation_ID (PK)

   Room_number (FK)

   Customer_Id (FK)

   Date

   Price

i found that introducing a reservation ID will simplify the code and might have better performance advantages because it will make it faster to retrieve and update the reservation records,, but introducing the reservation_ID will break the 3rd normal form. So should i break the 3rd normal form to gain the simplicity and performance advantages.

BR

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would add Reservation_ID as the primary key. This does not break 3rd normal form; although I'm sure that could be argued, this isn't the proper place.  Instead that should be on Stack Overflow.